# Convert list of integers into chunks

Tags: java

I am reading from an ArrayList of 64000 values, 64 values at a time.After reading 64 values, it should be converted to an array and the list should be cleared to accommodate a second set of 64 values. This method should go on until it reaches the end of the original list.I wrote the following code, but looks like my output list is returning more than 64 values which is not my goal.Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
 ArrayList<Integer> output = extractIntegers(array);//some method in the code
 for(int i=0;i<output.size();i+=64)
 {
     blocks.addAll(output.subList(i, i+64));
     Integer[] b = blocks.toArray(new Integer[blocks.size()]);
     System.out.println(b);
     b = null;
 }
```

Comment: You need to clear `blocks` every time. In fact, what is `blocks`? Why not just call `output.subList(i,i+64).toArray()`? And you cannot print an array like that (you can print a List).

Comment: will blocks.clear(); work in my case? Or should I use remove? How can I make a list empty?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
ArrayList<Integer> output = extractIntegers(array);//some method in the code
for(int i=0;i<output.size();i+=64)
{                
    blocks=output.subList(i, i+64);
    Integer[] b=blocks.toArray(new Integer[blocks.size()]);

    System.out.println(b);  
}
```

Comment: Why won't you empty the array in the end? Or the blocks list ?

Comment: You don't need to empty `b` because it goes out of scope next anyway. The `blocks` is reset in every iteration (no more `addAll`, just overwrite the whole instance).

Answer (score 0):

Did you empty `blocks` at the end of each iteration? Posted code doesn't show it which probably might be the cause of your problem.